# generate eos keypair from Mnemonic/Seed

Tags: eosjs

is it possible and is it secure to generate eos keypair using bip39 mnemonic seed?

something like:

```
const hdkey = require('hdkey')
const wif = require('wif')
const ecc = require('eosjs-ecc')
const bip39 = require('bip39')
const mnemonic = 'real flame win provide layer trigger soda erode upset rate beef wrist fame design merit'
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedHex(mnemonic)
const master = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(Buffer(seed, 'hex'))
const node = master.derive("m/44'/194'/0'/0/0")
console.log("publicKey: "+ecc.PublicKey(node._publicKey).toString())
console.log("privateKey: "+wif.encode(128, node._privateKey, false))
```